# Back wheel is slipping when pedals are rotating both the front and back sprockets

Tags: crankset, rear-wheel, drivetrain-slipping

When pedaling, the front chainring turns the back crankset which rotates the back wheel. However, sometimes it slips, meaning when rotating the pedals which turns the back crankset does not turn the back wheel.

Comment: Welcome to Bike Exchange. What exactly is slipping?  Your chain? Or is it the wheel slipping where it attaches to the frame.  Go ahead and edit your question to add additional detail and the group can make a better assessment of your problem and some solutions.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a duplicate (though it might be) but [a recent question of mine](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/86464/7309) has some discussion that might help you pin it down

Answer (score 1):

The question is somewhat vague as to what is actually slipping. "*If*" it is the rear hub that is slipping then some possible causes are the hub on your back wheel has either stuck or damaged pawls, or broken pawl springs, or altogether.

Comment: Welcome to Bike Exchange. The questioner needs to add a bit more information before we can confidently assess an answer. You may have pegged it, but with the question vague to all but the original questioner, no one can be sure. I would suggest adding more detail to your answer on how to RESOLVE the question, and also word it in a way that fits the currently vague question.